# Error in ------Area <- function(L, W) { : could not find function "-<-"

Tags: r

I am new to R, trying to learn it to pass my analytics class. For the life of me, I cannot identify the package that I need that contains the Area function (L, W).

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post code, preferably not in the title of the post. There are tons of examples of good R questions on SO. Poke around and see what folks who received useful help did to help contributors help askers. That includes properly structured code blocks. Just a quick look at the code that should not be in the title suggests you have an extra `-` before the assignment and/or a series of `-`s before the function name.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the recommendation. I have tried looking around and cannot find what I need. I am extremely unfamiliar to programming in general. My code is as follows: Area <- function(L,W) {
  a1 <- L * W
  print(paste0("The area of a rectangle of sides", L, "x", W, "is", a1, sep = " "))  
  }

Comment: No, I'm suggesting you look around so you can post a proper question vs put random characters in the post title without any real context. That code should be in the body of the question.

Comment: Area <- function(L,W) {
  a1 <- L * W
Error in ------Area <- function(L, W) { : could not find function "-<-"

Comment: put that in the _body_ of the question, properly indented so it's a code-block.

Comment: but from what you've posted you have the `print(…)` on the same line as the `L * W` calculation and that's invalid R syntax. put it on another line

Answer (score 0):

There's no package I know of with that function, sounds like something that might have been created as an exercise.

```
Area <- function(L, W){L * W}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jordo82. If you were to build a simple formula/ command to execute the area of a rectangle, how might you do it? Again, im very new to this and have been wrapped up on this. Very frustrated at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You really should, at least, make an attempt to post a reproducible example and more details as to what you have already tried. Normally area is derived using the [x,y] coordinate pairs. This allows one to calculate area on non-rectangular data such as circles and polygons, using the vertices.

Here is a function that calculates area of the specified x,y coordinate vectors

```
area <- function (x, y) {
  if (any(length(x) != length(y))) 
    stop("x and y must be the same length")
  n <- length(x)  
  return( 0.5 * (abs(sum(x[1:(n - 1)] * y[2:n]) + x[n] * y[1] -
          sum(x[2:n] * y[1:(n - 1)]) + x[1] * y[n])) )
    }
```

Now, we can apply the function to a simple rectangle, with four coordinate pairs representing the corners.

```
x <- c(0, 0, 20, 20)   
y <- c(0, 20, 20, 0)
plot(x,y,pch=19)
area(x,y)
```

And, a circle representing a more complex shape with 12,289 vertices.

```
p <- seq(0, 2 * pi, len=3 * 2^12 + 1)
  x <- cos(p)
  y <- sin(p)
plot(x,y, type="l")
area(x,y)
```

If you absolutely need the [length, width] solution for a rectangle, you have already been given the answer by @Jordo82. Area is simply L*W but, the trick is getting length and width from the coordinate pairs in an arbitrary graph space. Using the rectangle from the previous example we can get at [L,W] by taking the difference of [x,y] min and max. You really do not need a function to do any of this.

```
x <- c(0, 0, 20, 20)   
y <- c(0, 20, 20, 0)
area <- function(x, y) { abs(min(y) - max(y)) * abs(min(x) - max(x)) }
area(x,y)
```